# Couldn't copy google sheet using Google API Key

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-api, google-drive-api

I have been working for a project that makes use of google-APIs to create/write and read google sheets. I also wanted to duplicate a template on every user onboard.

I'm trying to use **Files.Copy** **API**, but I'm unable to do so with the Google API Key. It always restricts the copy with an error message ''**This error may be due to using an insufficient credential type. Try using OAuth 2.0.**"

Is there any way to copy the google sheet using only **API key** other than **OAuth**?

Comment: Can I ask you about `I also wanted to duplicate a template on every user onboard.`? Where is the source file? And where do you want to copy the files to?

Comment: I have the temolate created by another user and shared the same is shared  with service account email.

Comment: Thank you for replying. How about using the service account?

Comment: No, an API key is not sufficient for writing

Comment: Thank you guys for the response :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps that I followed to overcome this issue.

1. Create a folder in GSuite drive
2. Share the folder with the service account
3. Move the template sheet that needs to be copied to the shared folder
4. Share the template key with the service account
5. User File.Copy (Drive API) to copy the template sheet to the shard folder itself.

This way you can achieve both copying a template and viewing it. Without a shared folder, it ain't possible to view the sheets created by a service account

Previously I wasn't able to copy the sheet because it was owned by another user and had to get the consent from the user through oAuth. Now its resolved by sharing the parent folder of the template with the service account email.